# jQueryMobileとReact.jsは組み合わせられませんか？

Tags: reactjs, jquery-mobile

いろいろやっても動きませんでしたので、
質問させてください。

JavaScriptには慣れていませんので、
常識的な変なこと聞いていたら申し訳ないです。

こちらのサイトのReact.jsのサンプルを動かしました。

Backbone.JSからAngular2まで、全9大JavaScriptフレームワークを書き比べた! - paiza開発日誌
http://paiza.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/11/Backbone_JS%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89Angular2%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%80%81%E5%85%A89%E5%A4%A7JavaScript%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E6%AF%94%E3%81%B9

jsfiddle で掲載されていたものから、HTML全体を取得して
ローカルに保存し動作を確認してから

jQueryMobileのデザインを対応させようとして

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

このように記載ました。

しかし、HTMLが、JavaScriptから出力されるためなのか、
JQueryMobileのデザインにはなってくれませんでした。

次のサイトをみると、class定義をすればいいとありましたが、

A Software Engineer Blog: react.jsとjquery mobile
http://kentandx.blogspot.jp/2015/07/reactjsjquery-mobile.html

input タグのclass定義がわからず、
jQueryMoblieでは、inputタグは
`<div class="ui-field-contain">`
で囲って指定するようですが、
React.js側で、divタグを指定したところで、
やはり、JQueryMoblieのデザインにはなりませんでした。

何か、React.jsの出力を、jQueryMobileに対応させる方法など
ありますでしょうか？

一応、試しているソースをのせておきます。
よろしくおねがいします。

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true" language="JavaScript 1.7">
var MyApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
      return {
          firstName: this.props.firstName,
          lastName:  this.props.lastName,
      }
  },
  handleChange: function(){
      var firstName = this.refs.firstName.getDOMNode().value;
      var lastName = this.refs.lastName.getDOMNode().value;
      this.setState({
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
              });
  },
  render: function() {
    var fullName = this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName;
    return (
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
        First name: <input ref="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.firstName}/><br/>
        Last name: <input ref="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.lastName}/><br/>
        Full name: {fullName}
        </div>);
  }
});
React.render(<MyApp firstName="Taro" lastName="Yamada" />, document.body);
//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render: function() {
    var fullName = this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName;
    return (
        <div className="ui-field-contain">
        First name: <input className="name" ref="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.firstName}/><br/>
        Last name: <input className="name" ref="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.lastName}/><br/>
        Full name: {fullName}
        </div>);
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    $(".name").textinput().textinput("refresh");
}
```

jQueryMobile は動的に生成した要素に適用したい場合 refresh しなければなりませんので、componentDidMount() 内で refresh させれば期待する動きになると思います。
また React.jsのJSXでは class は className で指定します。

Comment: お返事おそくなりました。動作確認できました。非常に的確なお返事、ありがとうございます。すごいです。